# How to restrict Customer type lookup in CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

By default customer type lookups allow both account and contact entity types. i just need to restrict the customer lookup on the quotation form so it only allows contacts. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=JS7:

"Put the following into the opportunity's OnLoad event:

crmForm.all.customerid.setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1");

This tells the customer lookup to only include the account (object type code 1). A value of 2 forces the lookup to only display contacts."

Answer (score 0):

For CRM 2011 the code is:

```
document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1"); //Sets the "Account to default value"
```